# How can I transform a rmse of a log scaled target?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, linear, rms

I am struggling to interpret the rmse of a model with the log scaled target. When the rmse is 0.6, how can I know the real rmse value in order to know if the model is acceptable or not ?

Comment: Dup of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371529/interpreting-rmse-of-log-values

Comment: I saw that answer but it doesn't answer  how to transform back the rmse...